# Virtual Smart Card lock

Tags: windows, smartcard, tpm

I have already asked this question on [Microsoft Q&A site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/92377/virtual-smart-card-lock.html), but unfortunately the problem has not been resolved.
In our Windows domain infrastructure(Win Server 2019), we use virtual smart cards for authorization in Windows, connecting to VPN, etc. Unfortunately, after 5 incorrect attempts to enter the PIN code, the virtual smart card is permanently blocked (not TPM module).

> **Get-tpm**

```
TpmPresent : True
TpmReady : True
TpmEnabled : True
TpmActivated : True
TpmOwned : True
RestartPending : True
ManufacturerId : 1398033696
ManufacturerIdTxt : STM
ManufacturerVersion : 74.8.17568.5511
ManufacturerVersionFull20 : 74.8.17568.5511
ManagedAuthLevel : Full
OwnerAuth :
OwnerClearDisabled : False
AutoProvisioning : Enabled
LockedOut : False
LockoutHealTime : 10 minutes
LockoutCount : 5
LockoutMax : 31
SelfTest : {}
```

Can I somehow increase the number of incorrect input attempts or make the lock non-permanent?
I know about admin PIN or PUK unlocking, but this is not exactly what I would like to use.
Thanks for any ideas.